# Getting XKB remaped arrow keys (ISO_Level3_Shift + HJKL) to work properly with the WIN key

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xkb

I've seen some posts on how to remap arrow keys with XKB, but although they work mostly fine, no method so far (except using different groups, which becomes an hassle to manage with Gnome keyboard-setup) seems to work together with <kbd>Windows</kbd>.

I'm trying to remap my keyboard so that HJKL keys allow me to have navigation with a `ISO_Level3` modifier.

I tried both assigning the arrow keys directly in ISO_Level3 and by **redirecting** the key (I give both examples in the code below).

They work alone fine (i.e. I can use the arrow keys by themselves) and they also work with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and<kbd>ALT</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + `LVL3` + <kbd>H</kbd> = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>LEFT</kbd>) but they **don't work together with <kbd>Windows</kbd>**.

My symbol file is:

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {
      name[Group1] = "Satan";
      include "us"

      // middle row
      key <AC06> {
        symbols =   [ h, H, Left ],
        actions =   [ NoAction(), NoAction(), Redirect(key=<LEFT>) ] };
      key <AC07> {      [ j, J, Down ] };
      key <AC08> {      [ k, K, Up ] };
      key <AC09> {      [ l, L, Right ] };

      key <AC10> {      [ ISO_Level3_Shift, colon, semicolon, colon ]};
      modifier_map Mod5 { ISO_Level3_Shift };
};
```